# stacked bar plot missing bar

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, group-by, bar-chart

I am trying to do a stacked bar plot of the following data

```
CySecTyp
         sec_type  GrossNewWeek  GrossOldWeek  DiffNotional
currency                                                   
CAD          GOVT  4.521113e+08  4.187604e+08  3.335081e+07
CAD         LOCAL  1.138226e+09  1.149303e+09 -1.107680e+07
CZK          GOVT  4.902150e+07  4.864998e+07  3.715170e+05
EUR          CORP  3.530248e+09  3.426971e+09  1.032772e+08
EUR          GOVT  1.364417e+10  1.615410e+10 -2.509922e+09
EUR         LOCAL  4.034059e+08  3.993782e+08  4.027674e+06
GBP          CORP  2.885294e+08  2.871592e+08  1.370228e+06
GBP          GOVT  6.925399e+10  7.050976e+10 -1.255770e+09
JPY          GOVT  1.188722e+09  1.304017e+09 -1.152955e+08
RUB          GOVT  4.983984e+07  5.000739e+07 -1.675481e+05
SEK          GOVT  2.174349e+08  2.168506e+08  5.843469e+05
USD           ABS  4.220868e+08  3.133468e+08  1.087400e+08
USD        AGENCY  1.917368e+08  1.914581e+08  2.787500e+05
USD          CORP  1.665336e+10  1.576663e+10  8.867344e+08
USD          GOVT  2.493034e+10  3.202521e+10 -7.094873e+09
USD       MUNITAX  7.201788e+08  7.315638e+08 -1.138500e+07
USD          POOL  4.342897e+09  4.348640e+09 -5.743000e+06
USD        SENIOR  1.505225e+06  1.651213e+06 -1.459879e+05
ZAR          GOVT  1.442477e+08  2.380834e+08 -9.383571e+07

CySecTyp.set_index('sec_type',append=True)['DiffNotional'].unstack().plot(kind="bar",stacked=True,figsize=(10,8))
plt.ylabel('Gross Loan Amount in Billions')
plt.title('Weekly Changes in Securities')
plt.show()
```

I noticed that I  had some missing bars in the plot. I have read similar question in other forums but couldnt figure out the issue.

Q(1) Why are some values missing?

Q(2) How can I sort the values based on a combination currency/sectype (higher to lower values for each currency/sec combination)

Thank you

Comment: Which specific values are missing in your bar chart?

Comment: iam not able to see  this row                                                               EUR          GOVT  1.364417e+10  1.615410e+10 -2.509922e+09